# What does this mean in English? (from math to English)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a set, $s \in  S, G:S\rightarrow S$ and $(P,Sc, u )$.

$\exists! F:P\rightarrow S$ that

i)$F(u) = s$

ii)$\forall x \in P, F(Sc(x))=G(F(x))$

I'm not trying to prove this, I'm just struggling too hard to understand the second point. Can someone translate into words I can think of?

Edit: (P,Sc,u) Yes, I'm talking about successor and I'm sorry!

$P$ is a set,$u\in P, Sc:P\rightarrow P$
in which

i$)\forall x\in P, Sc(x) \neq u$,

ii)If $A\subseteq P, u\in A $ and $  a\in A $  imply  that $Sc(a)\in A$, then $A=P$

Comment: I don't understand what $(P,Sc,u)$ should mean; apparently $P$ is a set, and $u \in P$. But I don't know what Sc is. Perhaps "successor"?

Comment: What is the triple $(P, Sc, u)$ supposed to be?

Comment: On the second line, “There is a unique $F$, mapping $P$ to $S$, such that”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to "rephrase the terminology in natural language", let me try to explain what is *really* being said, here.

First of all, $P$ is a *special* kind of set, called an *inductive* set. If you like, you can think of it being "the natural numbers", but there are other inductive sets one might define. The "special" element $u \in P$ is what you might call a "seed element", or a "base element". It begins the induction chain, which is essentially what (ii) is for. For $p \in P$, I will write $p'$ for $Sc(p)$, for notational reasons.

So given a function $g:S \to S$, and some point $s \in S$, we are asserting the existence of a *unique* function:

$f: P \to S$, with some additional constraints:

1) $f(u) = s$. We call this "the initial value of $f$".

2) $f(p') = g(f(p))$, in other words, the "next value" of $f$ is determined by taking $g$ of the "previous value".

This process is called "definition by recursion" (of $f$), and I will give you an example, so it seems a bit less imposing.

Let's first actually use $P = \Bbb N$, with $u = 0$, and $p' = p+1$ (we'll assume for the sake of argument that addition in $\Bbb N$ has already been satisfactorily defined). For our set $S$ we'll use $\Bbb N$ again. For our element $s$ we'll choose $0$, as well.

For our function $g: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, we'll use the function defined by: $g(n) = n+2$. So what is the function $f$ your theorem asserts exists?

Well, first we must have:

$f(0) = 0$.

Next, we must have:

$f(1) = f(0+1) = g(f(0)) = g(0) = 0+2 = 2$.

Similarly, we have:

$f(2) = f(1+1) = g(f(1)) = g(2) = 2+2 = 4$.

Continuing:

$f(3) = f(2+1) = g(f(2)) = g(4) = 4+2 = 6$.

If we knew that for a given $k$, we had:

$f(k) = 2k$, then we would also have:

$f(k+1) = g(f(k)) = g(2k) = 2k + 2 = 2(k+1)$.

It thus holds by your property (ii) of our $P = \Bbb N$, that $f$ is indeed the "doubling" function:

$f(n) = 2n$

lending credence to the intuitive notion that "multiplying by $2$" is just repeated addition of $2$'s.

---

This is not a proof of the existence/uniqueness of said function $f$, it's an illustrative example to show how functions from $P \to S$ can be expressed "compactly" by specifying "the seed value", and the "generating rule".

Comment: how can i be like you in 10 days for my exam :/

Comment: You did mention there are other inductive sets one can define, (I'm assuming you are callin Peano's system (as in my book) an inductive set). I've found a proof that says "This guarantees that there exists only one peano's system". Also they call it "positive integers". I'm thinkin maybe this only works for the number "1", and not really for any $u$.

Comment: Inductive sets, or more generally natural number objects, are *not* unique, but they all are *very similar*. And yes, one way to create "a different kind of natural number" would be to start with $u$, which might be "an actual concept", like a barleycorn (the measurement), or an elephant. One can "define" natural numbers as the intersection of all inductive sets, but this doesn't work if your set theory has ur-elements. However, under certain assumptions (in second order logic), the natural numbers are unique-up to a unique isomorphism.

Comment: sorry what does "unique-up" mean? and yeah, the proof involves the unique isomorphism, thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: The dash is just punctuation, so read it as: "unique..." (pause) "....up to a unique isomorphism".

Answer (score 0):

For every element x, that belongs to P, the application of F to the successor of x is equal to application of G to the result of application of F to x.